# Difference between git "open existing repository" and "clone existing repository"

Tags: git, svn, git-bash

After installing [Git Bash](http://git-scm.com/downloads), right clicking a new blank folder in Windows Explorer and hit `Git Gui` I get the form as snapshot.

As a SVN user, I can't tell the differences between `open` and `clone` action from the UI. What are the differences between the two i.e. in SVN I just have `check out` command?

A quick google search on [diference between git "open existing repository" and "clone existing repository"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=diference%20between%20git%20%22open%20existing%20repository%22%20and%20%22clone%20existing%20repository%22) give me nothing useful.

[image]

Comment: Git itself doesn't have a concept of "opening" a repository. It's probably just a way tell the GUI which existing repository to start working with (viewing, updating, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Clone means copy a new repo from a remote source.
Open means open an existing local repo, one you have already cloned or created.

Answer (score 1):

Since Git is distributed (as opposed to SVN which is centralized), you have the choice of:

- opening a local Git repo you could have created with `git init`, or clone from a remote.
- cloning from a remote repo (which can be another repo on your hard drive, or a remote network repo accessible through https or ssh)

The difference with SVN is SVN will always require an svn url, and **has no notion of "cloning"**: you just get SVN HEAD in your workspace.

Since Git always represents the *full* history, you either open one locally, or clone one.